# secure string.xml value when reverse engineer happen

Tags: encryption, string.xml

How can i hide o encrypt the **values of my string.xml fi**le when someone try to reverse engineer? So that i can secure my apk. I already implemented proguard and minify in my build.gradle.

Please help.